# Switching between blue / green services in Kubernetes using UI page

Tags: kubernetes

The project is going with a new technology stack and I need to do a new CI / CD implementation. I started to play with Kubernetes and how to do blue / green deployment via command line. I managed to do switch manually via command line changing label selector in the service to filter green or blue pods. Now, what exactly I am looking for is kind of UI page where QA guys could do a switch between blue and green instances once they finished to test the application on staging server.

So:

1. Web site is deployed to staging environment (i.e. green);
2. QA test it and confirm that everything is fine;
3. QA navigate to some UI to make green instance live and blue to staging;

Are there any tools on the market for this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jenkins allows you to construct a CI/CD pipeline that meets your requirements. Here's an example of a pipeline using an input step to decide which environment to deploy to. All you would need to do is wire the stages together.

[image: blueocean]

Here's an example of the pipeline code (declarative) used to create the example:

```java
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Deploy Staging') {
      steps {
        echo 'deploying to staging'
      }
    }
    stage('Test Staging') {
      steps {
        echo 'testing staging env'
      }
    }
    stage('Blue/Green?') {
      steps {
        input(message: 'Blue/Green?', id: 'deploy', ok: 'deploy?', parameters: [choice(choices: 'blue\ngreen', description: 'Select an environment', name: 'PROD_ENV')])
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Other tools that provide similar capabilities are Rundeck, Stackstorm or Ansible Tower.

Answer (score 1):

After a while, I decided to proceed with TeamCity+Octopus as I did for the previous .NET stack. QA / Dev teams got accustomed to the way they are doing deployments. Even though Octopus doesn't have a first-class Kubernetes support, I implemented my own way to do releases to Kubernetes clusters via custom linux target with Calamari. Blue / Green deployments were implemented using manual intervention step in Octopus.